# Arguments and function call

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Here is my code:

```
from telegram.ext import *
updater=Updater(token="")
dis = updater.dispatcher
def echo(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text = update.message.txt)
dis.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text,echo))
def main():
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

How is the **echo** function called and how are the arguments sent to the function. Which arguments are actually sent?

Answer (score 0):

`MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo)` saves a saves a reference to the `echo` function in the `MessageHandler` object, and `dis.add_handler()` registers this handler in the `updater.dispatcher` object. The Telegram module calls the function automatically when appropriate, passing the `update` and `context` arguments.

This is an example of a [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

Comment: I understand about the callback function , but can you explain more about arguments please

Comment: The Telegram documentation should explain what they represent.